# Splitting a string and mapping it to a JSON Array in Snaplogic

Tags: string, jsonpath, mapper, snaplogic

Afternoon.
I am pulling fields out of salesforce using snaplogic and then calling a rest api with the results.
One of the fields that I am mapping to the POST JSON Body needs to be an array.
One of the fields that I am pulling out of salesforce is string that is semi-colon delimited.
Looking at the snaplogic documentation there is a split(';') function that I can call.
In the mapping snap I get this error whenever I try and add an expression to the end of the Salesforce field:

```
cannot lookup a property on a null value
```

Is there an example somewhere of splitting a string in a mapper snap and applying it to a rest html body?
The documentation on the snaplogic site will verbose is nevertheless unhelpful.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `split()` method to output an array from the mapper snap.

Following is a sample pipeline:

[image: sample pipeline]

Input JSON in the JSON generator:

```
[
    {
        "msg" : "Test 1;Test 2;Test 3"
    }
]
```

All settings are left to default.

Mapper Snap:

[image: mapper snap]

Expression: `$msg.split(';')`

Output: `[{"msg_array":["Test 1","Test 2","Test 3"]}]`